# case_when in RStudio, creating high, average and low levels of a variable

Tags: r

Trying to get my data arranged for an interaction plot based on a high, average and low level of a variable (`mean_all_belonging` - this is a numeric variable). This code works up until I use `case_when`.

```
team_leader_match$BelongingLevels <- ntile(team_leader_match$mean_all_belonging, 3)
head(team_leader_match$BelongingLevels)

team_leader_match$BelongingLevels

x <- team_leader_match$mean_all_belonging


  team_leader_match$BelongingGroup <-
  case_when(x > mean(x)+sd(x) ~ "high",
            x < mean(x)+sd(x) & x > mean(x)-sd(x) ~ "average",
            x < mean(x)-sd(x) ~ "low")
```

The desired output should have this structure:

```
## # A tibble: 3 × 2
##   BelongingGroup     n
##        <chr> <int>
## 1    average   182
## 2       high    32
## 3        low    30
```

And instead, only NAs appear for me:

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [41] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [81] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Edit: `dput` for `team_leader_match$BelongingGroups`

```
> dput(team_leader_match$BelongingGroups)
c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_)
```

Comment: Please consider giving a reproducible example.

Comment: You could make your example reproducible, e.g., by giving the `data team_leader_match` via `dput`.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. The `case_when()` clause works well. It is probably the input that is problematic. What does `class(x)` return?

Comment: `class(x)` returns `[1] numeric`